# Don't inflate response image with Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, kingfisher

I've switched to Kingfisher to download image files from URLs. I used to use Alamofire for this, and I would have to set `inflateResponseImage` to `false` so that my image wouldn't appear skewed. However, I can't find an equivalent for Kingfisher. Can anyone help me? This is what my Alamofire code was:

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseImage(inflateResponseImage: false) { response in
    if let image = response.result.value {
        completion(image)
    } else {
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```